# Find a Phone App

Tags: iphone

If you activate the find a phone app, does it automatically display the location services icon on all devices listed or only on the device you select from the list to pinpoint it’s location ?

Also will it display icon if that particular device is not sharing it’s location yet it is online?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which real-world problem you are trying to solve here ?

Comment: Please update the title of the question. Currently the title is asking for a phone app instead of describing the question.

Answer (score 1):

It triggers all devices as you load the web page, because until you search a particular device, the first option is 'All Devices'.

Having said that, I'm not seeing any location indicator on the iPads, only on the iPhones.

Just tested with a selection of devices in front of me, some mine, some my partner's.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So you are saying it does trigger the arrow icon in the upper left corner of screen when you bring up the app on all devices?

Comment: Yes, but seemingly only on the phones. My iPad is set to "share location from xxx's iPhone" which makes sense as it's only wifi. It appears to have no option to share it from itself, except, one would assume if it was lost, triggered from the iCloud page. I haven't tested this fully, just opened the find page & watched all the screens as I did it.

Comment: Thanks again!  One more question does the icon just come up for a few seconds and go away? 
Like you would have to be staring at it to notice.
I have a teenager that o am just keeping an eye on!

Comment: It's solid maybe a minute before it goes to hollow. I wasn't paying attention after that. It will show in the Location history though, if they get smart & start checking that.

Comment: @user364393 Based on your follow-up questions, it appears you're trying to solve some problem but you're starting with the solution and working backward.  If you can edit your question with the problem you're trying to solve, perhaps you'll get more answers?